# PHP decode JSON from cookie

Tags: php, arrays, json, cookies, encode

I'm trying to parse a JSON encoded string from a cookie and when I run json_decode() on the string it returns as null. It should be a simple operation - what am I missing?

```
/* Get */

    $cookie_exampleData = $_COOKIE['exmaple_data'];

    // Retrieves: '{\"FirstName\":\"Angus\",\"LastName\":\"MacGyver\",\"Email\":\"hello@email.com\",\"Phone\":\"8185555555\"}'

/* Decode */

    $cookie_exampleData_decoded = json_decode($cookie_exampleData);

/* Print */

    var_dump($cookie_exampleData_decoded);

    // Returns: NULL
```

Comment: `\"` makes your JSON invalid

Comment: @kingkero that's what print_r()'s printing. I don't have access to the system that's creating the cookie, but in a nutshell it's running json_encode() on an array and setting that string as the cookie's value.

Comment: it occurs that using `stripslashes` is common when reading from `$_GET`, `$_POST`, `$_COOKIE`. `JSON.stringify` indeed converts `{1:2}` into `"{\"1\":2}"` which is seamless inside same language but not in transport

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In this case, you need remove  escaped quotes:

```
$cookie_exampleData = stripslashes($_COOKIE['exmaple_data']);
```

See [stripslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php)

Comment: Thanks. I don't know anything about anything, so judging from @kingkero's comment above it seems odd that I have to unescape a JSON encoded string - shouldn't decoding handle that?

Comment: I would also like an answer to this question.

Comment: @mike_freegan Because from the OP`s question we see "strange" JSON-format ( with slashes ) => therefore before decoding we have to remove those slashes.

Comment: @technopeasant "shouldn't decoding handle that" => no, it shouldnt escape slashes. It`s not valid JSON.