# Getting value from cookie using json_decode

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

I am setting a cookie and that is working fine but for some reason I'm not able to retrieve the value of the cookie. I can see the cookie is set in the browser developer tools but when I try to `print_r` it comes up empty.

**Here is where I see the values of the cookie in developer tools.**

[image: Browser shows the cookie is set and has values]

**Here is where I'm trying to get the value that is currently not working:**

```
$additionalData = json_decode($_COOKIE['antennasNow'], true);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($additionalData);
echo '</pre>';
```

**Here is where I set the cookie in case it is helpful:**

```
setcookie('antennasNow', json_encode($cookieValue), time()+3600);
```

**And this is how I'm setting the value of the cookie in case it helps:**

```
$cookieValue = array(
        'base_Sku' => $base_Sku,
        'vhf_UHF_Type' => $vhf_UHF_Type,
        'ptc_Type' => $ptc_Type,
        'type_700_800_900' => $type_700_800_900,
        'band' => $band,
        'polarization' => $polarization,
        'gain_Sku' => $gain_Sku,
        'exposed_Dipole_Az_Pattern' => $exposed_Dipole_Az_Pattern,
        'collinear_Az_Pattern' => $collinear_Az_Pattern,
        'panel_Az_Pattern' => $panel_Az_Pattern,
        'dual_Input' => $dual_Input,
        'narrowband_Connector' => $narrowband_Connector,
        'beamtilt' => $beamtilt,
        'null_Fill' => $null_Fill,
        'heavy_Duty' => $heavy_Duty,
        'invert_Mount' => $invert_Mount,
    );
```

I followed these tips/steps from other threads:

[PHP decode JSON from cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28016042/php-decode-json-from-cookie)

[json_decode to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164404/json-decode-to-array)

[Storing PHP arrays in cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032007/storing-php-arrays-in-cookies)

Comment: If you `print_r($_COOKIE['antennasNow'])` directly (without attempting to decode first) do you see the raw data?

Comment: @ADyson yes, it prints this `{\"base_Sku\":\"ATC-G\",\"vhf_UHF_Type\":\"D\",\"ptc_Type\":\"\",\"type_700_800_900\":\"\",\"band\":\"1\",\"polarization\":\"V\",\"gain_Sku\":\"2\",\"exposed_Dipole_Az_Pattern\":\"D\",\"collinear_Az_Pattern\":\"\",\"panel_Az_Pattern\":\"\",\"dual_Input\":\"D2\",\"narrowband_Connector\":\"D7M\",\"beamtilt\":\"1\",\"null_Fill\":\"NF\",\"heavy_Duty\":\"HD\",\"invert_Mount\":\"INV\"}`

Comment: Hm, that looks like the data has somehow been escaped / double-encoded at some point, meaning it's no longer valid JSON and can't be decoded. All those backslashes need to go.

Comment: @ADyson thank you! I tried `stripslashes` previously but it didn't work but I now do `$jsonData = stripslashes($_COOKIE['antennasNow']);` and `$additionalData = json_decode($jsonData, true);` and now I have access to the data stored in `$additionalData`

Comment: That papers over the crack, but you could really do with finding out how it got corrupted in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your debug codes with this -

```
$additionalData = json_decode(stripslashes($_COOKIE['antennasNow']), true);
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($additionalData);
    echo '</pre>';
```